# Adding rows, columns, diagonals in a 2D array (java)

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main 
{
  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
    int i, j;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
    int array[][] = new int[4][4];

    System.out.println("Enter Numbers: ");

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        array[i][j] = reader.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Square: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
      for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
    System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

I have this code written in java that asks a user for 16 numbers and then prints the numbers in a 4x4 array. I have to find the sum of each individual column and each individual row and of each individual diagonal. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I would look at using Collections in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what you are even trying to do in your code, you just input and print 4x4 array. In java arrays are fixed you can use `ArrayList` and other built in classes to do this in easier way. This algorithm would be a good way for variable size of inputs since `4` can be replaced by any value:

```
int matrixWidthHeight = 4;
int rowSum[matrixWidthHeight];
int columnSum[matrixWidthHeight];

for (int i = 0; i < matrixWidthHeight; ++i) {
   for (int j = 0; j < matrixWidthHeight; ++j)
       rowSum[i] += arr[i][j];

   for (int j = 0; j < matrixWidthHeight; ++j)
       rowSum[i] += arr[j][i];
   
   sumDiagonal1 += arr[i][matrixWidthHeight - i]; // / diagonal sum
   sumDiagonal2 += arr[matrixWidthHeight - i][i]; // \ diagonal sum
}
```

I do not know how Java works behind the seen, but for array size of `4` you can do:

```
int rowSum[4];
int columnSum[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
   rowSum[i] += arr[i][0];
   rowSum[i] += arr[i][1];
   rowSum[i] += arr[i][2];
   rowSum[i] += arr[i][3];

   columnSum[i] += arr[0][i];
   columnSum[i] += arr[1][i];
   columnSum[i] += arr[2][i];
   columnSum[i] += arr[3][i];
   
   sumDiagonal1 += arr[i][4 - i]; // / diagonal sum
   sumDiagonal2 += arr[4 - i][i]; // \ diagonal sum
}
```

The first one is easy to adjust for all kind of sizes, but is N^2, the second one is N, but today this does not matter for matrix of 4x4, since it is 4 * 2 * 4 (32) loop ops, vs 4 loop ops isn't a big deal for today CPUs.

Comment: Please do not spoon-feed answers. Providing code without any explanation devoids OP of the chance to understand the problem at hand and how to solve it.

Comment: @Turing85 I updated my answer, I hope this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the length of an array after it's initialization in java. What you can do and should do here is to copy the content of the old array into a new array with more rows/columns. The same holds true for the diagonals.

Comment: thanks! i think i asked the question incorrectly. I edited it though. i meant to ask how to find the sum of each individual row, column, diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

In, Java, arrays are immutable in length, which means that you can't add or remove a column or row in your case. You might want to take a look at a `Collection`, such as `ArrayList`s. Those have an implementation which allows for scaling.

You can always read a bit more about `Collection`s [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/collections-in-java).

Comment: thanks! i think i asked the question incorrectly. I edited it though. i meant to ask how to find the sum of each individual row, column, diagonal.